# shell_exec requires full path name in php script on mac

Tags: php, macos, terminal, shell-exec

(Doing this on OSX, apologize if off-topic)

When I run the line of code

```
shell_exec("/usr/local/bin/gnuplot gnuplot_script7");
```

inside a php script, a file named gnuplot_output7.png is generated, as expected. But when I run the similar line of code

```
shell_exec("gnuplot gnuplot_script7");
```

no image is generated! This despite that if I type

```
gnuplot gnuplot_script7
```

on the OSX command line, the image is successfully generated.

I typed - echo $PATH on the command line and got back

```
/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/Library/PostgreSQL/8.4/bin/:/usr/local/git/bin:/usr/X11/bin
```

and when I typed

```
which gnuplot
```

on the command line I got back

```
/usr/local/bin/gnuplot
```

Answer (score 2):

Your user `$PATH` **isn't** the same as the user php is running.

---

**Solution**

1- Run `php` under **your** user (probably unsafe) and you can use:

```
shell_exec("gnuplot gnuplot_script7");
```

2 - Just use the `full path`:

```
 shell_exec("/usr/local/bin/gnuplot gnuplot_script7");
```